# How do i change the easy tabs page title to webBrowser1.DocumentTitle?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

This is what it should look like:
[image]

This is what it should look like 2nd Picture:
[image]

Program.cs

```
using EasyTabs;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Luke_Browser_Beta_Retry_2
{
    static class Program
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        AppContainer container = new AppContainer();
        container.Tabs.Add(
            new TitleBarTab(container)
            {
                Content = new frmBrowser
                {
                    Text = "New Tab"
                }
            }
            );
        container.SelectedTabIndex = 0;

        TitleBarTabsApplicationContext applicationContext = new TitleBarTabsApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.Start(container);
        Application.Run(applicationContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Heres my attempt

```
Content.Text = webBrowser1.DocumentTitle + | + New Tab;
```

So someone pls help me fix this I wanna make a really cool browser!

Comment: Where is your sample code to show that you've attempted this problem?

Comment: @Reap I put my code in

Comment: where is your attempt located? If you want it to change when you navigate to another page, you should add an event handler for when the page changes, and then add that piece of code there.

If this is the library you are using, which I'm not 100% sure, it seems you can add an event handler as there is one for this exact use case. Otherwise, please list the library you are using somewhere so we can find documentation on it to help you find an answer. See: https://github.com/lstratman/EasyTabs/blob/master/TitleBarTabs.cs#L724

Comment: @Reap nice thanks but  i really dont know where it goes like in program.cs? or appcontainter.cs?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put the `|` and `New Tab` inside double quotes in order for it to work, since they are both strings.

Both of those strings should also be a single string, so that it's more readable.

The above should be:

```
Content.Text = webBrowser1.DocumentTitle + "|New Tab";
```