# How do i change the easy tabs page title to webBrowser1.DocumentTitle Reupload

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

This is what it should look like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7jks.png

This is what it should look like 2nd Picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2k3k.png

Program.cs

```
using EasyTabs;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Luke_Browser_Beta_Retry_2
{
    static class Program
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        AppContainer container = new AppContainer();
        container.Tabs.Add(
            new TitleBarTab(container)
            {
                Content = new frmBrowser
                {
                    Text = "New Tab"
                }
            }
            );
        container.SelectedTabIndex = 0;

        TitleBarTabsApplicationContext applicationContext = new TitleBarTabsApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.Start(container);
        Application.Run(applicationContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Heres my attempt

```
Content.Text = webBrowser1.DocumentTitle + | + New Tab;
```

So someone pls help me fix this I wanna make a really cool browser!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i change the easy tabs page title to webBrowser1.DocumentTitle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66283695/how-do-i-change-the-easy-tabs-page-title-to-webbrowser1-documenttitle)

Comment: @Jimmy what do u mean? can u give me some code to fix it pls?